# Vapor bearer auth with UserAuthenticator() always fails with 401 Unauthorized

Tags: swift, authentication, bearer-token, vapor

I am new to Vapor and I am trying to add a login endpoint. I am following Vapor documentation on Bearer Authentication from https://docs.vapor.codes/security/authentication/#bearer

My implementation so far:

```
struct UserAuthenticator: AsyncBearerAuthenticator {

func authenticate(bearer: BearerAuthorization, for request: Request) async throws {
    typealias User = App.User

    let loginUser = try request.query.decode(LoginUserDTO.self)

    guard let user = try await User.query(on: request.db)
        .filter(\.$email == loginUser.email)
        .first(),
    let userId = user.id else {
        throw Abort(.notFound)
    }

    guard let userToken = try await UserToken.query(on: request.db)
        .filter(\.$user.$id == userId)
        .first() else {
        throw Abort(.notFound)
    }

    if bearer.token == userToken.value {
        request.auth.login(loginUser.toUser())
    }
}
```

}

My user `Model` class has an extension:

```
extension User: ModelAuthenticatable {
    static var usernameKey = \User.$email
    static var passwordHashKey = \User.$passwordHash

    func verify(password: String) throws -> Bool {
        self.passwordHash == password.generateHash(salt: salt)
    }
}
```

my routes file has this protected route:

```
    let protected = app.grouped(UserAuthenticator())
    protected.post("login") { request async throws -> ClientTokenReponse in
        let user: User = try request.auth.require(User.self)
        return ClientTokenReponse(token: "token")
    }
```

When I try to login with postman I always get a 401 Unauthorized, if I try to debug the UserAuthenticator class, it doesn't even stop at the breakpoint. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing two separate things, login and route protection.

`AsyncBearerAuthenticator` should not be used for the call to login, only for routes where the user should already be logged in with a token.

First the user should make a call to login to get a token. This can still be protected in some way, generally a user will have to provide a password. You can see this a bit further down in the Vapor documentation.

Your `UserAuthenticator` should only verify that the token is valid and match it to a user.

Comment: I actually thought the exact same thing, how can I be protecting the "login" route with the authenticaator when the user hasn't been authenticated yet, but this is what the docummentation says:

`Now that the User conforms to ModelAuthenticatable, we can create an authenticator for protecting the login route.`

    ```let passwordProtected = app.grouped(User.authenticator())
passwordProtected.post("login") { req -> User in
    try req.auth.require(User.self)
}
```

and obviously it always throws 401 on `try req.auth.require(User.self)`

Comment: So is my code in UserAuthenticator good or not? If so, should I just remove it from protecting the `login` route and in login route generate the token store it in the DB and send it back to the user right?

Comment: The documentation is a bit confusing. You need some form of "login" where the user passes some kind of password to the login call. If that password is valid, you create a token, otherwise they should get a 401.

Your UserAuthenticator should only check if the token is valid and find the user that belongs to that token, then login that user using `request.auth.login`. Generally JWT is used for tokens, which usually include the user id, which you can use to find the user in the database.

Comment: This page (https://docs.vapor.codes/security/authentication/#jwt) also has some more info, but you should not take the documentation too literally, it is there as an example, but it is definitely not a full secure solution.

Comment: I tried it with JWT before but the documentation seemed to be even more confusing and obviously didn't work because I tried it also with protecting the `login` route which again returned 401, so I decided to write the auth manually.

Comment: It is probably good to first decide on what kind of login/authentication strategy you want to use for your application, as this dictates what kind of implementation you want to use with Vapor. It is hard to tell you what the login endpoint should look like otherwise.